# Two Most Recent Dates - Is There a Gain?

Tags: powerquery

I need to group by HHID and find the two most recent dates, remove the oldest ones and determine if the most recent date has a larger score than the second most recent date.

[image]

I tried grouping by HHID but I am getting stuck getting the two most recent dates for each group of HHID. and I am not sure how to then tackle determining if the most recent score is larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a custom aggregation in `Table.Group` written in the `Advanced Editor`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"HHID", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Assessment", type text}, {"Question", type text}, {"Answers", type text}, 
        {"Points", Int64.Type}, {"Score", Int64.Type}}),

//May not need to Trim on your actual data
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{
        {"Assessment", Text.Trim, type text}, 
        {"Question", Text.Trim, type text}, 
        {"Answers", Text.Trim, type text}}),


    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"HHID"}, {
        {"Most Recent GT Penulatimate Score",(t)=>
            let 
                #"Most Recent Score" = t[Score]{List.PositionOf(t[Date], List.Max(t[Date]))},
                #"Penultimate Score" = t[Score]{List.PositionOf(t[Date],List.MaxN(t[Date],2){1})}
            in 
                try #"Most Recent Score" >  #"Penultimate Score" 
                otherwise null, type logical}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

I returned a *null* for the case where you only have a single date for the HHID. You could handle this some other way.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you learn this? In school, or watching YouTube videos? I really want to learn more. Either way, thank you so much again!

Comment: I learned mostly by examining answers by others; reading various blogs online; MS documentation; trial and error; etc.  By the way, since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: How would I be able to keep all the previous columns and add a new column with the Most Recent GT Penulatimate Score Column? Little late, I know.

Comment: @HollySzady Probably by adding an aggregation of `All Rows` to the current `Table.Group` aggregations, and then re-expanding. If that doesn't do what you want, I suggest you post a new question, with data **as text** (*not a screenshot*) and a picture of exactly what you want for output, along with any attempts at modifications.